# how can I use aws DB in JAVA application level?

Tags: playframework, amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0, tunneling

I used private server for my web application which is made by 'play!' 
However, because of some reasons, recently I changed my server environment to AWS (Amazon Web Server) 
Now I have a problem. 
Ever I try to run application, the application cannot connect to DB (Play Framework Error log: Cannot connect to database [default]) 
Somebody told me to do tunneling to access the database but I don't know how to do tunneling at Play! framwork (or JAVA) 
How can I do tunneling in source code (application) level?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look section "Configuring Play" at [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-19/)